# Java LDAP - Determine if user in a given group?

Tags: java, active-directory

We logon users to Active Directory via LDAP using the Java LDAP API.  We want to enhance our logon functionality to further check if the user is in a given AD group.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Current code:

```
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.ldap.*;

LdapContext ctx = null;
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, Config.get("ldap-url"));

try {
    Control[] connCtls = new Control[] {new FastBindConnectionControl()};
    ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, connCtls);
    ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "DOMAIN\\" + username);
    ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    ctx.reconnect(connCtls);
    /* TODO: Only return true if user is in group "ABC" */
    return true; //User authenticated
} catch (Exception e) {
    return false; //User could NOT be authenticated
} finally {
    ...
}
```

---

**Update**: See the solution below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We solved this with the class below.  Just call the authenticate method:

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.*;    
import javax.naming.*;    
import org.apache.log4j.Level;

public class LdapGroupAuthenticator {
    public static final String DISTINGUISHED_NAME = "distinguishedName";
    public static final String CN = "cn";
    public static final String MEMBER = "member";
    public static final String MEMBER_OF = "memberOf";
    public static final String SEARCH_BY_SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME = "(SAMAccountName={0})";
    public static final String SEARCH_GROUP_BY_GROUP_CN = "(&(objectCategory=group)(cn={0}))";

    /*
     * Prepares and returns CN that can be used for AD query
     * e.g. Converts "CN=**Dev - Test Group" to "**Dev - Test Group"
     * Converts CN=**Dev - Test Group,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com to "**Dev - Test Group"
     */
    public static String getCN(String cnName) {
        if (cnName != null && cnName.toUpperCase().startsWith("CN=")) {
            cnName = cnName.substring(3);
        }
        int position = cnName.indexOf(',');
        if (position == -1) {
            return cnName;
        } else {
            return cnName.substring(0, position);
        }
    }
    public static boolean isSame(String target, String candidate) {
        if (target != null && target.equalsIgnoreCase(candidate)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean authenticate(String domain, String username, String password) {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://1.2.3.4:389");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, domain + "\\" + username);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        DirContext ctx = null;
        String defaultSearchBase = "DC=DOMAIN,DC=com";
        String groupDistinguishedName = "DN=CN=DLS-APP-MyAdmin-C,OU=DLS File Permissions,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com";

        try {
            ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

            // userName is SAMAccountName
            SearchResult sr = executeSearchSingleResult(ctx, SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE, defaultSearchBase,
                    MessageFormat.format( SEARCH_BY_SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME, new Object[] {username}),
                    new String[] {DISTINGUISHED_NAME, CN, MEMBER_OF}
                    );

            String groupCN = getCN(groupDistinguishedName);
            HashMap processedUserGroups = new HashMap();
            HashMap unProcessedUserGroups = new HashMap();

            // Look for and process memberOf
            Attribute memberOf = sr.getAttributes().get(MEMBER_OF);
            if (memberOf != null) {
                for ( Enumeration e1 = memberOf.getAll() ; e1.hasMoreElements() ; ) {
                    String unprocessedGroupDN = e1.nextElement().toString();
                    String unprocessedGroupCN = getCN(unprocessedGroupDN);
                    // Quick check for direct membership
                    if (isSame (groupCN, unprocessedGroupCN) && isSame (groupDistinguishedName, unprocessedGroupDN)) {
                        Log.info(username + " is authorized.");
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        unProcessedUserGroups.put(unprocessedGroupDN, unprocessedGroupCN);
                    }
                }
                if (userMemberOf(ctx, defaultSearchBase, processedUserGroups, unProcessedUserGroups, groupCN, groupDistinguishedName)) {
                    Log.info(username + " is authorized.");
                    return true;
                }
            }

            Log.info(username + " is NOT authorized.");
            return false;
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            Log.info(username + " is NOT authenticated");
            return false;
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new SystemException(e);
        } finally {
            if (ctx != null) {
                try {
                    ctx.close();
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    throw new SystemException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean userMemberOf(DirContext ctx, String searchBase, HashMap processedUserGroups, HashMap unProcessedUserGroups, String groupCN, String groupDistinguishedName) throws NamingException {
        HashMap newUnProcessedGroups = new HashMap();
        for (Iterator entry = unProcessedUserGroups.keySet().iterator(); entry.hasNext();) {
            String  unprocessedGroupDistinguishedName = (String) entry.next();
            String unprocessedGroupCN = (String)unProcessedUserGroups.get(unprocessedGroupDistinguishedName);
            if ( processedUserGroups.get(unprocessedGroupDistinguishedName) != null) {
                Log.info("Found  : " + unprocessedGroupDistinguishedName +" in processedGroups. skipping further processing of it..." );
                // We already traversed this.
                continue;
            }
            if (isSame (groupCN, unprocessedGroupCN) && isSame (groupDistinguishedName, unprocessedGroupDistinguishedName)) {
                Log.info("Found Match DistinguishedName : " + unprocessedGroupDistinguishedName +", CN : " + unprocessedGroupCN );
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (Iterator entry = unProcessedUserGroups.keySet().iterator(); entry.hasNext();) {
            String  unprocessedGroupDistinguishedName = (String) entry.next();
            String unprocessedGroupCN = (String)unProcessedUserGroups.get(unprocessedGroupDistinguishedName);

            processedUserGroups.put(unprocessedGroupDistinguishedName, unprocessedGroupCN);

            // Fetch Groups in unprocessedGroupCN and put them in newUnProcessedGroups
            NamingEnumeration ns = executeSearch(ctx, SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE, searchBase,
                    MessageFormat.format( SEARCH_GROUP_BY_GROUP_CN, new Object[] {unprocessedGroupCN}),
                    new String[] {CN, DISTINGUISHED_NAME, MEMBER_OF});

            // Loop through the search results
            while (ns.hasMoreElements()) {
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) ns.next();

                // Make sure we're looking at correct distinguishedName, because we're querying by CN
                String userDistinguishedName = sr.getAttributes().get(DISTINGUISHED_NAME).get().toString();
                if (!isSame(unprocessedGroupDistinguishedName, userDistinguishedName)) {
                    Log.info("Processing CN : " + unprocessedGroupCN + ", DN : " + unprocessedGroupDistinguishedName +", Got DN : " + userDistinguishedName +", Ignoring...");
                    continue;
                }

                Log.info("Processing for memberOf CN : " + unprocessedGroupCN + ", DN : " + unprocessedGroupDistinguishedName);
                // Look for and process memberOf
                Attribute memberOf = sr.getAttributes().get(MEMBER_OF);
                if (memberOf != null) {
                    for ( Enumeration e1 = memberOf.getAll() ; e1.hasMoreElements() ; ) {
                        String unprocessedChildGroupDN = e1.nextElement().toString();
                        String unprocessedChildGroupCN = getCN(unprocessedChildGroupDN);
                        Log.info("Adding to List of un-processed groups : " + unprocessedChildGroupDN +", CN : " + unprocessedChildGroupCN);
                        newUnProcessedGroups.put(unprocessedChildGroupDN, unprocessedChildGroupCN);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (newUnProcessedGroups.size() == 0) {
            Log.info("newUnProcessedGroups.size() is 0. returning false...");
            return false;
        }

        //  process unProcessedUserGroups
        return userMemberOf(ctx, searchBase, processedUserGroups, newUnProcessedGroups, groupCN, groupDistinguishedName);
    }

    private static NamingEnumeration executeSearch(DirContext ctx, int searchScope,  String searchBase, String searchFilter, String[] attributes) throws NamingException {
        // Create the search controls
        SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();

        // Specify the attributes to return
        if (attributes != null) {
            searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(attributes);
        }

        // Specify the search scope
        searchCtls.setSearchScope(searchScope);

        // Search for objects using the filter
        NamingEnumeration result = ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter,searchCtls);
        return result;
    }

    private static SearchResult executeSearchSingleResult(DirContext ctx, int searchScope,  String searchBase, String searchFilter, String[] attributes) throws NamingException {
        NamingEnumeration result = executeSearch(ctx, searchScope,  searchBase, searchFilter, attributes);

        SearchResult sr = null;
        // Loop through the search results
        while (result.hasMoreElements()) {
            sr = (SearchResult) result.next();
            break;
        }
        return sr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note this is not quite complete because groups can be nested in Active Directory, so you will not get users who are member of a group by virtue of being a member of another group.  The right way to do this is to get the tokenGroups attribute of the user which contains the groups as a list of SIDs, however this is a binary attribute that needs to be decoded. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/alextch/archive/2007/06/18/sample-java-application-that-retrieves-group-membership-of-an-active-directory-user-account.aspx

Answer (score 18):

None of above code snippets didn't worked for me. After 1 day spending on Google and tomcat source following code worked well to find user groups.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.CompositeName;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.Name;
import javax.naming.NameParser;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

public class MemberOfTest{
    private static final String contextFactory = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    private static final String connectionURL = "ldap://HOST:PORT";
    private static final String connectionName = "CN=Query,CN=Users,DC=XXX,DC=XX";
    private static final String connectionPassword = "XXX";

    // Optioanl
    private static final String authentication = null;
    private static final String protocol = null;

    private static String username = "XXXX";

    private static final String MEMBER_OF = "memberOf";
    private static final String[] attrIdsToSearch = new String[] { MEMBER_OF };
    public static final String SEARCH_BY_SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME = "(sAMAccountName=%s)";
    public static final String SEARCH_GROUP_BY_GROUP_CN = "(&(objectCategory=group)(cn={0}))";
    private static String userBase = "DC=XXX,DC=XXX";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        // Configure our directory context environment.

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, contextFactory);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, connectionURL);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, connectionName);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, connectionPassword);
        if (authentication != null)
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, authentication);
        if (protocol != null)
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, protocol);

        InitialDirContext   context = new InitialDirContext(env);
        String              filter  = String.format(SEARCH_BY_SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME, username);
        SearchControls      constraints = new SearchControls();
        constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIdsToSearch);
        NamingEnumeration results = context.search(userBase, filter,constraints);
        // Fail if no entries found
        if (results == null || !results.hasMore()) {
            System.out.println("No result found");
            return;
        }

        // Get result for the first entry found
        SearchResult result = (SearchResult) results.next();

        // Get the entry's distinguished name
        NameParser parser = context.getNameParser("");
        Name contextName = parser.parse(context.getNameInNamespace());
        Name baseName = parser.parse(userBase);

        Name entryName = parser.parse(new CompositeName(result.getName())
                .get(0));

        // Get the entry's attributes
        Attributes attrs = result.getAttributes();
        Attribute attr = attrs.get(attrIdsToSearch[0]);

        NamingEnumeration e = attr.getAll();
        System.out.println("Member of");
        while (e.hasMore()) {
            String value = (String) e.next();
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Marcus's solution contains unknown classes/libraries (until you import them) and other irrelevant code while this solution is simple and working like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is with 'lookup': (to open an Ldap Context: look above examples)

```
 /**
  * Tests if an Active Directory user exists in an Active Directory group. 
  * @param ctx LDAP Context.
  * @param dnADGroup distinguishedName of group.
  * @param dnADUser distinguishedName of user.
  * @return True if user is member of group.
  */


public static boolean isMemberOfADGroup(LdapContext ctx, String dnADGroup, String dnADUser) {
  try {
   DirContext lookedContext = (DirContext) (ctx.lookup(dnADGroup));
   Attribute attrs = lookedContext.getAttributes("").get("member");
   for (int i = 0; i < attrs.size(); i++) {
    String foundMember = (String) attrs.get(i);
    if(foundMember.equals(dnADUser)) {
     return true;
    }
   }
  } catch (NamingException ex) {
   String msg = "There has been an error trying to determin a group membership for AD user with distinguishedName: "+dnADUser;
   System.out.println(msg);
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  return false;
 }
```

Comment: Note: this will not work if the number of entries > 1500

Answer (score 3):

LDAP lookup methods of finding whether a user is a member of a group are not correct, especially if you're talking about a logged on user. For a user that's actually logged on the list of groups varies depending on which computer the user logged on. That list needs to include groups from domain trusts, nested groups and local groups.

If you're looking for group memberships of the currently logged on user or a user that you're logging on with a username and password in Java, try [Waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com).

```
IWindowsAuthProvider prov = new WindowsAuthProviderImpl();
IWindowsIdentity identity = prov.logonUser("username", "password"); 
System.out.println("User identity: " + identity.getFqn()); 
for(IWindowsAccount group : identity.getGroups()) { 
    System.out.println(" " + group.getFqn() + " (" + group.getSidString() + ")"); 
}
```

Comment: This looks promising to me. But I found one problem here. I have created a local group "Test". Under this I manually added the current user. And when I ran above code it did not show me the "Test" group. Any pointer would really help me on this.

Comment: Make sure it's a security group, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781446%28v=ws.10%29.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

Following up on Sundaramurthi's answer, it could be done even more straightforward way, where you don't query for all the user's group:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=XXXX)(memberOf=CN=YYY,OU=_Common-Access,OU=Groups,OU=_CORP,DC=XXX,DC=XX))
```

where
    XXXX - user name
    XXX.XX - domain name
    YYY - group name

This lets you to just get an answer whether user is in a group or not.

So just do:

```
String userBase = "DC=XXX,DC=XX";
String CHECK_IF_USER_IN_GROUP = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s)(memberOf=CN=%s,OU=...,OU=...,OU=...,%s))";

String queryFilter = String.format(CHECK_IF_USER_IN_GROUP, user, group, userBase);

SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

NamingEnumeration results = context.search(userBase, queryFilter, constraints);

if (results == null) {
    throw new Exception("No answer from LDAP");
}

if (!results.hasMore()) {
    System.out.println("No result found");
    // user is not in the group
}
// user is in the group
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Java API specifics, but the generic way of doing this is adding a group check to the query/binding.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a working code using java naming ldap.
I used Spring LDAP, and the way you do it:
Get the User object, do a search on the username something like sAMAccountName=USERNAME

After you get the object you retreive the property memberOf -> this will be a list and check for a specific one in Java.

That is the only way I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

To query if a user belongs to a given group once you have established a connection you can query using either member or memberOf attribute in Active Directory.

Using memberOf Attribute :
filter used : (&(Group Member Attribute=Group DN)(objectClass=Group Object class))
Ex : (&(memberOf=CN=group,ou=qa_ou,dc=ppma,dc=org)(objectClass=group))

Using member Attribute :
filter used : (&(Group Member Attribute=User DN)(objectClass=Group Object class))
Ex : (&(member=CN=user,ou=qa_ou,dc=ppma,dc=org)(objectClass=group))

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer varies with installations of AD as well as other types of LDAP server.

We had to solve the same problem.  In the end we allowed the system administrator to provide us with an LDAP query-pattern where we substitute the user name (and group name if that needs to be variable too) into the pattern.

Comment: Thanks.  Why would the answer vary?  Seems to be a pretty standard query..  Do you happen to have a code sample that utilizes your LDAP query?

Comment: I suspect it varies in which version of AD because of how AD handles memberOf.  It stores group membership on the group and not on the user object.  The memberOf attribute on the User does not really exist and is calculated on the fly.  Better LDAP servers store it in both places as you would expect

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful:

[retrieves-group-membership for Active Directory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alextch/2007/06/18/sample-java-application-that-retrieves-group-membership-of-an-active-directory-user-account/)

And I have this piece of working code:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.CompositeName;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.Name;
import javax.naming.NameParser;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;

public class TestAD1 {

    private static String userBase = "DC=SomeName,DC=SomeName,DC=SomeName,DC=SomeName,DC=COM,DC=US";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestAD1 tad = new TestAD1();
        try {
            // Create a LDAP Context
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "ldap.serviceaccount@domain.com");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "drowssap");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://fully.qualified.server.name:389");
            LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
            InitialDirContext inidircontext = new InitialDirContext(env);
            DirContext dirctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
            System.out.println("Connection Successful.");

            // Print all attributes of the name in namespace
            SearchControls sctls = new SearchControls();
            String retatts[] = {"sn", "mail", "displayName", "sAMAccountName"};
            sctls.setReturningAttributes(retatts);
            sctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            String srchfilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(mail=*))";
            String srchbase = userBase;
            int totalresults = 0;

            NamingEnumeration answer = dirctx.search(srchbase, srchfilter, sctls);
            while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();
                totalresults++;
                System.out.println(">>>  " + sr.getName());

                Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                if (answer == null || !answer.hasMore()) {
                    System.out.println("No result found");
                    return;
                }

                if (attrs != null) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("    surname: " + attrs.get("sn").get());
                        System.out.println("    Email - ID: " + attrs.get("mail").get());
                        System.out.println("    User - ID: " + attrs.get("displayName").get());
                        System.out.println("    Account Name: " + attrs.get("sAMAccountName").get());
                        tad.GetGroups(inidircontext, attrs.get("sAMAccountName").get().toString());
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error listing attributes..." + e);

                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Total Results : " + totalresults);
                // close dir context
                dirctx.close();
            }

            ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem Search Active Directory..." + e);
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // Get all the groups.

    public void GetGroups(InitialDirContext context, String username) throws NamingException {
        String[] attrIdsToSearch = new String[]{"memberOf"};
        String SEARCH_BY_SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME = "(sAMAccountName=%s)";
        String filter = String.format(SEARCH_BY_SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME, username);
        SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
        constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIdsToSearch);
        NamingEnumeration results = context.search(userBase, filter, constraints);
        // Fail if no entries found
        if (results == null || !results.hasMore()) {
            System.out.println("No result found");
            return;
        }
        SearchResult result = (SearchResult) results.next();
        Attributes attrs = result.getAttributes();
        Attribute attr = attrs.get(attrIdsToSearch[0]);

        NamingEnumeration e = attr.getAll();
        System.out.println(username + " is Member of the following groups  : \n");
        while (e.hasMore()) {
            String value = (String) e.next();
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can modify the accepted answer from here: [Authenticating against Active Directory with Java on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390150/authenticating-against-active-directory-with-java-on-linux/390437) with the following:

```
String group="name of the group";
Iterator ig = groups.iterator();
Boolean bool=false;
while (ig.hasNext()) {
      String a=ig.next().toString();
      if (a.equals(group)) { 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Authentication succeeded!");   
                bool=true;
                // here you can do smth in case of success  
      }
}
if (bool==false){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Permission denied");   
}
```