# How to authorize an user against ldap group

Tags: java, ldap

I am writing a little tool, which can execute some operations within `ldap` (e.g. create user, delete user, assign user to group, read specific attributes, etc.) That works perfect.

Now I want to add a little security aspect. Only some users are allowed to execute these operations. That's why I want to check first, if the user who wants to do the executions is in a specific `ldap-group` (e.g. administrators). If the user is not in this group, he should get a message ("your are not authorized").

My standard login is like described everywhere:

```
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, LDAP_SERVER_URL + ":" + LDAP_PORT + "/" + LDAP_BASE_DN);
    if (LDAP_SERVER_URL.startsWith("ldaps")) {
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        env.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "com.ibm.devopscoc.ldap.util.LdapSSLSocketFactory");
        InputStream truststoreStream = LdapSSLSocketFactory.class.getResourceAsStream("truststoreldap.jks");
        LdapSSLSocketFactory.init(null, null, null, truststoreStream, "<password>", "JKS");
    }
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple"); 
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, probs.getAdminName());
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, probs.getAdminPassword());
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
```

Where do I have to specify the group?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You look him up in the directory and see whether he is a member of that group.

Comment: @EJP Perhaps OP wants to do this programatically.

Comment: @InfoEngi Try the solution provided in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570466/java-ldap-determine-if-user-in-a-given-group

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java LDAP - Determine if user in a given group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570466/java-ldap-determine-if-user-in-a-given-group)