# How to read users names in Active Directory using Java

Tags: java, active-directory

I need your help in finding the appropriate code for getting the stored users names and names in Active Directory by using a java code?
I am new to this field and I need your help and guidance since I need to design a report to retrieve the users names and names from the Active Directory.

Thanks for the help

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551809/how-to-connect-with-java-into-active-directory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may find this website helpful. Contains links for various Active Directory related functions using Java http://jeftek.com/222/using-java-code-with-active-directory/

Comment: Downvoting it. Because the link is not working anymore