# How to query AD using XPages?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

recently I have started working on how to query AD (Active Directory) in Lotus Notes - XPages. I came across a tool named LIZA (http://www.ldapexplorer.com/en/liza.htm), could anyone please let me know how do we use that tool? What is the tool all about and is it possible to integrate it with Lotus Notes. If not then what are the other ways to query AD using XPages.

Comment: Intrapages (http://intrapages.openntf.org) support AD authentication using ldap. download it and see how it is done

Answer (score 3):

JXPlorer and Liza are front-end applications. What you are looking for <strike>are not these droids</strike> is a (Java) library that you can call from XPages (most likely wrapped in a bean).

You can use the [Apache Directory](https://directory.apache.org/api/) to do this. One nice side effect: the API is used inside the [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) - another front-end application. So you would use the Studio to try the connection and browse the AD (or other LDAP) and the know what query and connection strings you need.

The alternative is to do it "the Java way"™ and use JNDI to connect to an LDAP as [suggested before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551809/how-to-connect-with-java-into-active-directory) by the Java guys.

I would use the Apache classes. Let us know how it goes!

Comment: stwissel I am trying with the Java way using JNDi to connect to LDAP. I have not yet completed, but I see a positive progress.

Comment: Trust me - you want to try the Apache classes

Comment: stwissel Yes I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Never used it myself, but could this been an alternative ? http://jxplorer.org/ Should be possible to use this with Java (agent, xpage, java) in Lotus Notes