# Querying account name & email from active directory via Java

Tags: java, active-directory

I would like to collect various information from an active directory using Java.
I've reviewed this post
[How to connect with Java into Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551809/how-to-connect-with-java-into-active-directory)

I'm able to connect to the active directory and get the user's display name, but I would like to get the user's account name (login username) and email (if one is configured).

Please advise if and how I can get this information.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to retrieve info using the required information key (name) like below to get the email .

```
   while (answer.hasMoreElements())
   {
        SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();

        System.out.println("user name" + sr.getName());
        Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
        System.out.println("email" + attrs.get("mail"));
   }
```

**EDIT :** check [here](http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm) the attributes list in ldap