# Retrieve list of users from active directory

Tags: java, active-directory

I am new to Active Directory. We have Active directory setup ready with following details:

`domain : company.local`
`host : <ip_address>`
`ou : adgroup`

What I want to do is fetch all the list of users under this active directory. I have no idea where I should start? Please let me know if you have any idea on this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from investigating some ldap basics code on java here:
[How to connect with Java into Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551809/how-to-connect-with-java-into-active-directory)