# How to to get the properties of an AD user using JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jnienv

I have been working with Java Native Interface for sometime now.
Suddenly I saw the topic of Active Directory users.I am completely new to this area.
Can Someone tell me what is this about?
Thanks in Advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to talk to Active Directory is to use a Java LDAP library.  This is covered by extensively in other Q&A's and off-site resources.  For example:

- [How to connect with Java into Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551809/how-to-connect-with-java-into-active-directory)

---

Now to your specific question:

> How to to get the properties of an AD user using JNI?

You *could* use JNI to access Active Directory.  You would need to:

1. Find a suitable native LDAP library.
2. Implement your own LDAP API classes for Java, with native methods for calling the native library
3. Write some C code to bridge the Java native calls to calls ro the native LDAP library (using JNI).
4. Solve the extra build / test / deployment / portability problems that come with any native code project.

Once you have done that, use your shiny new API to issue the appropriate LDAP query.

In short: it could be done, but there is *no real benefit* in doing it.

---

Suggested read: [The Law of the Instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument).