# How can i check id and password from database

Tags: java, mysql

I want to check `userid` and `password` from database. Is it necessary to store id and password to string first? I am trying to check it by `resultset.first()` method as my table has only one row but it is not working.

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answered, but I will comment that you should _not_ be storing plain text passwords in your database.

Comment: Look into password hashing and salting, never store passwords in plain text.

Comment: `It is not working` is not good description of error. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786813/java-client-authentication-without-a-servlet/48800576#48800576) is my answer about authentication, maybe look there and get your things together.

Comment: Ok thanks but how can i check userid??

Comment: @DujanaAbrar if you find userid in your table it is valid. If you do not find it it is invalid. But invalid user id should result in same error as invalid password.

Comment: I assume your ids and passwords are strings so it makes sense to store them as strings in the database. You can get the user by writing a query that selects the user where id = 'id' and password = 'password'. You should also do a null check if you want to use resultset.first().

Comment: Thanks @JuliusHörger.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one row, you can either hash or encrypt the userid-password combination.
When user enter the user credentials, hash those details and search in db if its exist or not.
If its exist, it will return that row or if its not exist, it will return null.