# How to validate username and password using Active Directory or LDAP in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I want to implement the validate ID and password using AD or LDAP but couldn't find any example or package. How do i implement this in Android studio

Comment: How to login using AD? why do you need that, what is the scenario you are addressing, please elaborate more and add what you have tried and did not work.

Comment: I want to validate a username and password using AD when users tries to login. I couldn't find any example or packages in android studio

Comment: I will suppose that the AD is on a Microsoft machine you are connected with over LAN! am I right?, i.e instead of authentication against DB/Google / facebook, you want to accept only users from your LAN, because there is no AD on Android device, are we on  the same page?, because if that is the case, you need to change this question title.

Comment: Yes you are correct. How do i do that in Android studio.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390150/authenticating-against-active-directory-with-java-on-linux), you can also take a look at some third party libraries like [ADAL](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-android), [Auth0](https://auth0.com/authenticate/android/active-directory/), [ioplex](http://www.ioplex.com/jespa.html).

Comment: No i didn't i created an API in python and authenticated the users

Comment: If you find a solution please do post it here.